# Get value into text field using combobox

Tags: php, javascript, html, combobox

I want to get value into text field from database when the value is selected from combo box

p.s: the value in combo box and the value I want into text field come from same table in database

Comment: You will have to learn some PHP, Javascript and SQL for that.

Answer (score 2):

if the value in the select box is the same as the value you want in the text field, you can do this with jQuery:

```
$("select").on('change',function(){
    $("input").val($("select option:selected").val());
});​
```

just replace `select` and `input` with selectors for those fields, and it's all handled client-side, here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JKirchartz/JwjX3/

Comment: which value you need. @MohammedAhsan

Answer (score 0):

my friend said that:

```
$('select').change(function(){
            var t = $('select').val();
            $('input').val(t);            
          });
```